# Author-year citation call-out to be repeated at the start of the formatted bibliographic item

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm using natbib package and I'd like to have a bibliography where :

- the citation in the text are like : **[Kent, 2000]** or **[Kent and Lane, 2000]**  or **[Kent et al., 2000]** (in bold)
- and in the bibliography : **[Kent et al., year]** Kent, C., Lane, L., Allen, B. (2000). The title of the article. Journal, etc

It is kind of a mix between "apalike" and "alpha" but my biggest problem is to have the brackets in the bibliography. I tried to edit the .bst files or via makebst but I was lost in it and didn't find the place where specify the brackets in the biblio... :-)

I hope it is clear, and someone has an idea ! Thks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please elaborate on the use case you have in mind. Are you concerned that your readers are experiencing difficulties associating the string "[Kent, 2000]" (presumably generated with a `\citep` instruction, right?) in the body of the document with "Kent, C. (2000)..." in the formatted bibliography unless you provide a "[Kent, 2000]"  prefix? Similarly, are they having a hard time connecting "[Kent et al., 2000]" in the body of the document with "Kent, C., Lane, L., Allen, B. (2000) ... " in the bibliography unless they're also shown a "[Kent et al., 2000]" prefix?

Comment: BibTeX is rather outdated and its very complicated to realize some things. If ever possible I would suggest switching to BibLaTeX, where most of these things can be done rather easily.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the title of your posting to clarify its intended objective. (The square-brackets part isn't the crucial message, is it?) Feel free to revert if you disagree.

Comment: @Mico : No problem for the title, thks. I am not concerned that readers won't understand, I just find it more readable this way. Mainly because I have several citations from the same authors.
And yes, in the text the \citep command works just fine

I'm still discovering latex world and I have already worked with natbib. And I'm using it for the chapterbib option in order to have one bibliography each chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Here a small fix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\NAT@open{[\bfseries}
\renewcommand\NAT@close{]}
\xpatchcmd\@lbibitem{\item[\hfil\NAT@anchor{#2}{\NAT@num}]}{\item[\citep{#2}\NAT@anchor{#2}{\NAT@num}]}{}{}
\begin{document}
Text \citep{article-full}

Text \citep{book-full}


\bibliographystyle{newapa}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

The justification of the label is yours ;-)

[image]